# Getting account assets data with MEXC API

Tags: python

**Need some help with MEXC API**

https://mxcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/contract_v1_en/?javascript#get-all-informations-of-user-39-s-asset

I need to get account assets data from MEXC with Python

I checked previous answers but they didn't work for me.

That's what I tried:

```
import requests, hmac, hashlib, time

api_key = 'abcde'
api_secret = 'abcde'

# API endpoint
url = 'https://contract.mexc.com/api/v1/private/account/assets'

# Generate signature
timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
prehash = 'GET' + url + 'access_key=' + api_key + '&t=' + timestamp
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), prehash.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'api-key': api_key,
    't': timestamp,
    'sign': signature
}

# Send GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Response -> 401: No authority!

Answer (score 0):

For signature you can use this code:

```
def generate_signature(api_key, api_secret, req_time, sign_params=None):
    if sign_params:
        sign_params = urlencode(sign_params, quote_via=quote)
        to_sign = f"{api_key}{req_time}{sign_params}"
    else:
        to_sign = f"{api_key}{req_time}"

    sign = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return sign

req_time = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

quantity = 0.5
sign_params = {
    "symbol": symbol,
    "price": 200.01,
    "vol": quantity,
    "side": 1,
    "type": 1,
    # Add any other parameters required by the API
}

signature = generate_signature(api_key, api_secret, req_time)
```